# Android 2.3 default icons (Gingerbread)

Tags: android, icons, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have searched it already about 2 days over the web. All what I've found are custom sets. Also I've found a few similar topics there but all answers were like "They can be found in the source (SDK)". I downloaded the latest SDK, and found out only a few icons from Gingerbread. I'm really stuck. All what i want is just the full set(mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi) of default icons (Menu Icons, Status Bar Icons, Action Bar Icons, Tab Icons, Dialog Icons, etc) for Android 2.3 Gingerbread. For example, this is how menu icons look like http://uploadpie.com/AZFJs.

Is there designers who has experience with designing for Gingerbread? I really need your help.

Comment: just a thought : designing for Gingerbread may allow to target most of the install base right now, but 4.x is already at more than 25% and it will only grow in the coming months. Designing for that version might make more sense.

Comment: But 4.x devices cost too much. We need to buy a lot of devices for our employees and that's why we decided to choose devices running Android 2.3.

Answer (score 1):

You can find these icons under the following folder:

[android-installation-directory]/platforms/android-10/data/res/drawable-hdpi

Once you have the hdpi icons, you can easily use a tool like GIMP to resize them to lower resolutions like mdpi and ldpi.

Hope this helps.

Best Regards,
Anay

Comment: As I wrote I've looked in this folder and there is only a few icons for 2.3. And you don't need to use so rediculous way to get mdpi and ldpi because it is already in this folder.